# How do I skip a certain number and continue?

Tags: java, for-loop

I was working on a program that user gives any number between 1 and 20 and choose between Addition and Multiplication, the program will calculate the basic addition or multiplication that result is n(input).

For example,

if input is 4 and Addition, the program gives the answer like:

4 is 4

4 is 3 and 1

4 is 2 and 2

if input is 9 and Multiplication, the program gives the answer like:

9 is 9*1

9 is 3*3

And it can't repeat the same answers like

6 is 3*2

6 is 2*3

My problem is multiplication part.
I still couldn't figure it out how to skip 2 (like above). It keeps ends at 9 is 9*1 and not giving it more because I coded that if remainder is not 0, end the program.

But I don't know how to do it. Below is what I did so far..
x is a first letter for multiplication and j is a second number for multiplication.

```
class Main {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
 Scanner sin = new Scanner (System.in);
 System.out.println ("Please enter an integer between 1 and 20: ");
 int nNatalie = sin.nextInt();
 sin.nextLine();
 int nHalf = nNatalie / 2;
 int j = 1;

 if (1 > nNatalie || nNatalie > 20) {
  System.out.println ("Invalid Number");
 }

 else {
  System.out.println ("Addition or Multiplication?");
  String word = sin.nextLine();

  if (word.equals("Addition")) {
    System.out.println(nNatalie + " is " + nNatalie);
    for (int i = nNatalie - 1; i >= nHalf; i--){
      if (j <= i) {
        System.out.println(nNatalie + " is " + i + " and " + j);
        j++;
      }
    }
  }

  else if (word.equals("Multiplication")) {
    for (int x = nNatalie; x >= j;){
      if (nNatalie%j != 0) {
        continue;
      }
      System.out.println(nNatalie + " is " + x + "*" + j + ".");
      j++;
      x = nNatalie / j;
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. How did you initialize `j`? If you step through for you 9 case and we *assume* j starts at 1, the first loop, It will print: "9 is 9*1" then j becomes 2 and x becomes 4. So then it will just loop because you never change x or j if `nNatalie%j!=0` where 9%2 is equal to 1 and nothing will change during iteration.

Comment: Your `x` variable is pretty much useless. You can do `nNatalie%j==0` to see if it is divisible by j, then `int x = nNatalie/x`. Your for loop should probably be `for(int j = 1; j<nNatalie; j++)` That way j always increments.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer between 1 and 20: ");
        int nNatalie = sin.nextInt();
        sin.nextLine();
        int nHalf = nNatalie / 2;
        int j = 1;

        if (1 > nNatalie || nNatalie > 20) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Addition or Multiplication?");
            String word = sin.nextLine();

            if (word.equals("Addition")) {
                System.out.println(nNatalie + " is " + nNatalie);
                for (int i = nNatalie - 1; i >= nHalf; i--) {
                    if (j <= i) {
                        System.out.println(nNatalie + " is " + i + " and " + j);
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (word.equals("Multiplication")) {
                
                for(int i = 1; i < nNatalie; i++) {
                    
                    if(nNatalie%i!=0) {}
                    else {
                        System.out.println(nNatalie + " is " + i + " * " + nNatalie/i);
                    }
                    
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation of the code would be nice for future reference.